# Ansibleでgit clone時に作成されるファイルの権限を変更したい

Tags: ansible

Ansibleでgitモジュールを使用時にdestオプションでファイルを作成し、
git cloneを実行する時に、権限を変更することは可能でしょうか。

```
- name: git clone
  git:
    repo: http://git.com/gitbucket/example.git
    dest: /home/example/
      owner: vagrant
      group: vagrant
      mode: 0755
    version: master
```

や

```
- name: git clone
  git:
    repo: http://git.com/gitbucket/example.git
    dest: /home/example/
    owner: vagrant
    group: vagrant
    mode: 0755
    version: master
```

を試しましたが、エラーになってしまいました。
書き方を統一したいので

```
owner=vagrant
```

のような書き方ではなく

```
owner: vagrant
```

と書きたいです。宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

本家に同じと思しき質問がありました。[How to switch a user per task or set of tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344777/how-to-switch-a-user-per-task-or-set-of-tasks)

`ansible` 1.9 以降であれば、`become_user`で実行ユーザを指定できるらしいので、
質問の例であれば、`become: vagrant`の記述を追加すると実現できると思います。
(`sudo_user`でもできるようです。現在どちらが推奨かまではよくわかりません)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。modeを変更するのは難しいということでしょうか。